# How to add all the elements of a dynamic field from a form in an email?

Tags: javascript, html

I am desperate (and new to JS, although I am constantly learning).

I am doing an 'email generator' which allows via 'mailto' to open the mail manager and generate the sending of an email. In the long term and when my project is finished, it will allow me to save time at work in sending emails.

The only problem is that I have a dynamic field to insert and it is not taken into account. I would like to be able to add as many fields as I want in the form and that all the content of the fields is found in the email.
The code I have is at the bottom of the subject.

I tried adding the elements by doing form.name.value but I only have the first element taken into account. I also tried, in the **ajouterInput_text ()** function, to add a var which takes into account each new element added in the form but nothing works ...

If you have an idea, I'm a pioneer, and at the same time, it will allow me to learn more!

Thank you beforehand !

B4LBU

P.S. I want to have only one html file and not go through php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AJOUT DE CHAMPS</title>
  </head>

  <!-- FORMULE POUR ENVOI DU MAIL -->
  <script language="javascript">
    function envoyer(formulaire) {
      window.location.href =
        "mailto:ADRESSEMAIL@MAIL.FR?subject=AJOUT DE CHAMP &body=Bonjour%0D%0D" +
        totalchampenplus +
        "";
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <form name="formulaire" action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <div id="container">
        <button onclick="ajouterInput_text()">Ajouter un champ texte</button>
        <br />
      </div>

      <!-- AJOUT DU CHAMPS EN PLUS-->
      <script>
        var totalchampenplus = "";
        var id = 0;
        function ajouterInput_text() {
          id++;
          var container = document.getElementById("container");
          var input = document.createElement("input");
          input.setAttribute("type", "text");
          input.setAttribute("id", id);
          input.setAttribute("name", "champenplus");
          input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Champ n°" + id);
          container.appendChild(input);
          container.innerHTML += "<br>";
          totalchampenplus =
            totalchampenplus + ", " + document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        }
      </script>

      <br />
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-outline-success"
        onclick="envoyer(this.form)"
      >
        ENVOYER
      </button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need a `<form>` at all. You use a `<form>` when you want to submit formData to a server. You're not doing that.

Comment: Can you explain what are those inputs for? And why would a *text field* be an input instead of a `textarea`?

Comment: a form allows me to have an easy-to-fill and interactive interface so that I can then generate my email. If you have any ideas of how to adapt this I'm interested

Comment: I don't know how to adapt something I don't know how it's supposed to work and what its job is. I'm having hard time to understand what are those input fields for... How is your script supposed to work? Why you cannot remove a text field? When you add a new text field all the other fields content are erased. Can you please rephrase your question and explain what are you exactly after? What means *" generate my email"*??

Comment: You're not generating any email, as far as I can see you're just trying to concatenate strings to your email **body**. I don't know why would you want N fields instead of just one textarea.

Comment: These inputs are to add lines according to the number of elements that I have to declare in my email.
I only have one item to declare in the textfields, so I don't need to use textarea. apart from that, it allows me to have a simpler layout in the mail.

Comment: I have regular reports to make. They are always the same and the form of the mails is always the same.

So I had the idea of making a form, to fill in all the elements necessary for the report and then retrieve the information so that the elements of the form can be written where I want them in the email. The idea of using mailto is that I can only use one html file which I can simply share with other coworkers who are doing the same reports.

The number of certain elements vary according to the folder concerned by the email, hence the dynamic fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're building... hopefully this might help:

- You don't need a `<form>`
- Buttons should be of `type=button` (since are "submit" by default)
- Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Always. Use `on*` handlers only when creating brand new elements from in-memory.
- Don't destroy your existent fields content.
- Iterate your elements and get their values using  [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and than [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) using your desired delimiter
- Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
const EL = (sel, PAR) => (PAR || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, PAR) => (PAR || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const enc = (str) => encodeURIComponent(str);

const EL_fields = EL("#fields");
const EL_add = EL("#add");
const EL_send = EL("#send");

function send() {

  const MAIL = "ADRESSEMAIL@MAIL.FR";
  const SUBJ = "AJOUT DE CHAMP";
  let   body = "Bonjour ";
  body += [...ELS(".field", EL_fields)].map((EL) => EL.value).join("\n");
  
  const href = `mailto:${MAIL}?subject=${enc(SUBJ)}&body=${enc(body)}`;
  
  console.log(href);
  location.href = href; 
}

function add() {
  const EL_input = ELNew("input", {
    type: "text",
    className: "field"
  });
  EL("#fields").append(EL_input);
  EL_input.focus();
}

EL_add.addEventListener("click", add);
EL_send.addEventListener("click", send);
```

```css
#fields { display: flex; flex-flow:column;}
.field { margin: 3px 0; }
```

```html
<div id="fields"></div>
<button id="add" type="button">Ajouter</button>
<button id="send" type="button">ENVOYER</button>
```